# In what story did Honor Harrington address the Weapons Development Board on the grav lance?

Tags: story-identification, honorverse

In David Weber's **On Basilisk Station** (end of chapter thirty-two), Andrew Yerensky asked Honor Harrington to address the Weapons Development Board.  Honor responded:

> "Well, Commodore Yerensky, I don't see how I could possibly turn your request down.  It happens that I *do* have strong feelings about the new armament--" her smile grew even broader "--and I'd be *delighted* to share them with Admiral Hemphill and her colleagues."

I could have sworn that I read a short story that had Honor evaluating the new weapons and explaining how she would have proceeded with the old weapons.  However, I've been unable to locate it in the anthologies.

Assuming that I'm not crazy (I know, a true leap of faith), does anyone know the name of this story?  I'd also be interested in the author (if not Weber) and locations where the story can be found, but I could probably find those with the story title.

Comment: "With One Stone" by Timothy Zahn from "The Service of the Sword" has a brief mention of it: "To him, it had been borderline criminal stupidity on Hemphill's part, and the rumor mill had it that Captain Harrington had said so directly to her face at the Weapons Development Board hearing afterward. Not in so many words, of course"

Comment: There are other references to what happened as well.  It was one of the the things that Parks had against Harrington when she was Sarnow's flag captain in **The Short Victorious War**.  But what I'm talking about is an actual story that covered it with both Harrington and Hemphill at the time it occurred.  Not people talking about it afterward.  In particular, I recall her explaining what she would have done instead if she had had traditional armament.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything in the comics either

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will be mentioned in-depth in "With one stone" from "In the service of the sword".

I'm not sure, but this is the one story AFTER Basilisk and BEFORE Yeltsin mission. I remember it ended with Hemphill reading about proto-FTL communication in Silesia. Only place where it could happen and fits timeline.

If that's not it, I'm pretty much sure it was in a story where Cardones was on a separate mission with ONI? But it may be the same story.

UPDATE: Going through the story in question and all relevant books an amendment is in order.
I have the same exact deja vu as Brythan. I think it was somewhere. Unfortunately I don't believe there is such a story. I think - it's my opinion only - that repeated mentions of the "incident" in several books and stories make it much more whole in my mind, creating an image of a story...